# Как получить последовательный список кнопок с панели задач для текущего виртуального рабочего стола?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-10

Сейчас перебираю все окна и с помощью метода `IsWindowOnCurrentVirtualDesktop` интерфейса `IVirtualDesktopManager` определяю что окно находится на текущем столе.

Кроме окон с панели задач получаю множество других. Что, в общем-то, не критично. Хотя тоже хотелось бы исправить. Основная проблема в определении последовательности. Как известно, пользователь может вручную изменить положение кнопки в панели задач.

Как определить последовательность?

Comment: А почему бы просто не отсортировать список по координате верхнего левого угла?